# How to capture error of process with stream?

Tags: elixir

I am importing a CSV into DB, I parse it and process each entry:

```
stream= File.stream!(path)
    |> CSVParser.parse_stream
    |> Stream.map(fn row ->
      case row do
        [_] -> nil
         _  -> row
      end
      end)
    |> Stream.chunk(chunck_n, step, [])
    |> Task.async_stream(CsvsController, :chunk_handler_fn, [process_name, db_map, entity_name, entity_id, entity_ios2, table_name, invite?, background_job_id], max_concurrency: 10)



Task.start_link(Stream, :run, [stream])
```

there would be hundred of chunks, processed via `CsvsController` but how can I capture error that would stop the current process? as `Task.start_link` is linked to the current process..

Comment: _Sidenote:_ you probably want to handle an empty list `[] -> nil` as well as the list having exactly one element as you are doing now: `[_] -> nil`.

Comment: oh, year, will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the `Task` is linked to your process, this process will receive a `:DOWN` info message with a signature `{:DOWN, _, :process, _pid, _reason}`. Assuming this code is inside the `GenServer`, you might just implement the handler:

```
def handle_info({:DOWN, _, :process, _pid, _reason}, state) do
  ...
end
```

And do whatever you want there.

---

#### Example of `GenServer` to handle this (incomplete, but you get the idea):

```
defmodule CsvImporter do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def process!(path), do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:process, path})

  def handle_call({:process, path}, _from, state) do
    stream = path
             |> File.stream!()
             |> CSVParser.parse_stream()
             .....

    {:ok, pid} = Task.start_link(Stream, :run, [stream])  
    {:reply, pid, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:DOWN, _, :process, _pid, reason}, state) do
    # check **reason** for whether it was finished
    #   unexpectedly and do something
  end
end
```

Now you are to put it into your supervision tree and just call `CsvImporter.process!(path)` when needed.

---

The more I think about this, the more I am convinced you actually don’t need a task at all. Just `cast` to this `GenServer`, process by the `GenServer` itself (`cast`s are async) and you are all set.

Comment: But I am in a phoenix controller.. how would I get the message?

Comment: That is generally a bad idea to spawn tasks from inside a controller. Introduce a `GenServer`, that will be responsible for handling everything and delegate the execution of long-running process there.

Comment: You are always welcome. Future you will thank you for introducing a `GenServer` for handling processes, trust me :)

Comment: I read a lot of GenServer, but this is the first time to use it in real life.. but how would I have the same GenServer for handling import CSV tasks? or shall I create a GenServer for each import task?

Comment: Nope, one `GenServer` is perfectly enough. I will update the answer with a short example in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Done. Please note, that within `GenServer` implementation you might get rid of `Task` at all, see the last comment.

Comment: Thanks for update, but what if two users, each sent his CSV file via `CsvImporter.process!(path)` ? there won't be a problem, as each one on a different process with different pid as: `Task.start_link`  , right?

Comment: Right. Two tasks will be spawned, one per `path`.

Comment: Last question please, as you called `GenServer.call` inside `CsvImporter.process!`, but `start_link ` was not called, how would the server get started?

Comment: **Now you are to put it into your supervision tree and just call `CsvImporter.process!(path)` when needed.** In your `Application` add `worker(...)`, there are examples commented out generated by `mix`.

Comment: Got it, as I will have only one instance of `CsvImporter`, each user has some attributes regarding his import task, thus, storing all users tasks attributes into one state, I would need a key for each user .. what do you recommend then?

Comment: You have many options here: either pass everything to the call to `CsvImporter.process!` (it might accept as many parameters as you want,) or just lookup these parameters somewhere else, or maintain the `user ⇒ options` hash in a state of this `GenServer` (this is the variable that is passed through all `call`s and `cast`s and is called `state` in my example; you might initiate it in `init`/`start_link` to whatever you want. I would go with just passing everything as arguments to `process!` for starters.

Comment: Yea, as having all users attributes in the server state, if the server crashed, then all states got lost.. but passing attributes to process! then each process would maintain its attributes.. as I am trying to grasp the option here..

Comment: Use `DETS` to maintain a persistent state, or rely on that the server does actually rarely crash, unless it’s designed to crash often.